# How to show my app name in two line in android in QVGA

Tags: android

I used my app name as `Seecycle Free` in a string. XML file and retrieve it in the Android manifest file. It appears fine in all devices but in QVGA device its appear in one line.
Why this happen, is there any solution by which my app name appears in two-line in QVGA device also, just as it appears in other devices.

Comment: That totally depends on device resolution BTW I think inserting \n will do the job

Comment: But how can i use \n in my string.xml file..if i use seecycles \n free it shows error in xml file

Answer (score 0):

create custom title instead of using default title:

for that u need to create an xml file in layouts similar to this:
You can also add images here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/myTitle"
      android:text="This is my new title"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:typeface="serif"
       />
```

In java u need to add:

```
    //beforesetcontentView
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    //after setcontentview
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);

        txt.setText("ur title");
```

In manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@style/customTheme" />
```

create a file themes.xml in res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>   
    </style> 
</resources>
```

finally create styles.xml in res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
   <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>                   
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Only for giving app name i have to do so this thing..but in the documentation it is defined that we can specify app name in android:label in manifest file..and its working fine for all devices except QVGA where it come in the same line instead of two line